# Horizontal Image Clear

Tags: css, image

I cannot get these thumbnail images to stack horizontally and clear the text here:

http://svgcuts.com/blog/2016/04/09/fairy-cottage-svg-kit/

I can add a float:left to the line:

```
191 .entry .ngg-galleryoverview .ngg-gallery-thumbnail img {float: left;}
```

But the text below keeps wrapping around the containers.

Comment: Questions asking for debugging help should include an [mcve], can you please update your question?

Comment: Display inline! Important

Comment: And please add some HTML and CSS to your posts!!!!

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought I gave enough to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect `ngg-galleryoverview` in developer tools you'll see it has collapsed when you float it's children. (aka: it no longer stretches to contain them.) The quickest way to fix this if you'd like to float the children is adding:

```
.ngg-galleryoverview {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cjspurgeon. This solution worked and was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your website, you can use `flexbox` to achieve what you want.

I noticed the wrapper for the thumbnails and came up with the code:

```
.entry .ngg-galleryoverview {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: -15px 0px 30px 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Notice that I just added:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

---

It works well for me:
[image: Flexbox in action!]

---

Comment: Great solution @tico. Went with the simple css fix for now.